# How many zeros at the end?

Tags: number-theory

How many zeros are at the end of the number $236!$? Are there any special formulas or ways to solve this that would work for the factorial of any number?

Thanks, 
|-(<>)-| Tie Fighter

Comment: Yes, there are formulas.  I'll just say here that you need to count how many factors of 5 divide $236!.$

Comment: $\lfloor 236 /5 \rfloor = 47$ multiples of $5$; $\lfloor47/5\rfloor =  9$ multiples of $25$; $\lfloor9/5\rfloor =  1$ multiple of $125$ giving $47+9+1 = 57$ multiples of $5$ contributing to the value of $236!$, hence $57$ zeroes at the end.